# Automatic ping check program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, tkinter, status-monitoring

Am I commenting enough? Are my variables properly following correct styling format? Is there a more efficient way to code my "Label coloring" conditions?

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import re

running = False # Infinite loop condition
idle_status = 'To begin, please press "Start"' # Message for Idle Status

# Start, Stop & Scanning functions
def start():
    Status.configure(text='Loading, please wait...')
    global running
    running = True

def stop():
    global running
    running = False
    Status.configure(text=idle_status, background="Grey")
    StatusPing.configure(text="", background="Grey")

def scanning():
    if running:
        output = subprocess.check_output("ping 104.160.131.1", shell = False, universal_newlines=True).splitlines()
        for i in output:
            if "Packets" in i: var1 = int(re.search(r'\d+', str(re.findall(r'Lost =\s\d*',i))).group())
            if "Minimum" in i: var2 = int(re.search(r'\d+', str(re.findall(r'Average =\s\d*',i))).group())
    Status.configure(text="Packet lost: {0}".format(var1))
    StatusPing.configure(text="Average ms: {0}".format(var2))

    # Packet loss label coloring
    if var1 == 0:
        Status.configure(background="Green")
    else:
        Status.configure(background="Red")

    # Ping Status label coloring
    if var2 <= 35:
        StatusPing.configure(background="Green")
    if 35 < var2 < 70:
        StatusPing.configure(background="Yellow")
    if var2 >= 70:
        StatusPing.configure(background="Red")
    root.after(10000, scanning)

# GUI
root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x120")
root.wm_title("Ping Checker")

# Ping Check Label
Status = Label(root, text = idle_status, height="0", width="30", background="Grey")
Status.pack(pady=1) # For visible division between two labels
StatusPing = Label(root, height="0", width="30", background="Grey")
StatusPing.pack()

# Start & Stop Buttons
Start = Button (root, text = "Turn on", command = start).pack()
Stop = Button (root, text = "Turn off", command = stop).pack()

root.after(10000, scanning) # Global Loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

**Naming**

The elephant in the room: names like `var1` and `var2` really hinder the readibility. `var1` probably means `has_packet_loss`, `var2` -> `latency`. Naming is hard, but it also is a fundamental property of readable code.

**Ternary**

You got repetition in

```
if var1 == 0: # has_packet_loss
    Status.configure(background="Green")
else:
    Status.configure(background="Red")
```

Becomes:

```
  status_color = "Red" if has_packet_loss else "Green"
  Status.configure(background=status_color)
```

**Comments**

You are commenting weird things: `# Start & End Button` is a thing I clearly see from the code, but the general purpose of the script is not immediately obvious. I suggest avoiding line-by-line comments and instead go for a docstring explaining the general purpose.

**Logic extraction**

`StatusPing.configure` is repeated 3 times:

```
if var2 <= 35:
    StatusPing.configure(background="Green")
if 35 < var2 < 70:
    StatusPing.configure(background="Yellow")
if var2 >= 70:
    StatusPing.configure(background="Red")
```

Write a function to determine background color and use it to avoid this repetition (Or a list of tuples)

**Named constants**

Define parameters at the start and use them later, this makes the code easier to re-use and makes it funnier to tinker (pun intended) with it. For example the ID to ping, the size of the widget, the colours, the messages...

Comment: Can you verify I understand the Ternary suggestion? `status_color = "Red" if has_packet_loss else "Green"` works because `has_packet_loss` is an integer, and is checked. Because it's value is 0 the program goes to the else statement. Am I using the right terminology in my attempt at an explanation?

Comment: @JohnSeuss Yes, nice explanation. You may add `== 0` for explicitness

Comment: I edited my original post with a new function `status_ping`. Is this what you meant with your Logic extraction suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Note: Bear in mind that you are relying on the OS's ability to correctly calculate packet loss. (Please see: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30940/difference-between-ping-timed-out-and-destination-host-unreachable)

You may wish to check for such phrases as 'Destination host unreachable' in your output as Windows does not count those responses as lost packets.

To bullet-proof your code, you might want to call the subprocess.check_output method from within a try...except. Losing your network connection during the call can result in an unexpected error which will prevent your scanning function from reaching its last line and looping.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions to Ternary and Logic Extraction @Caridorc suggestions

```
def scanning():
    if running:
        output = subprocess.check_output("ping 104.160.131.1", shell = False, universal_newlines=True).splitlines()
        for i in output:
            if "Packets" in i: packet_loss = int(re.search(r'\d+', str(re.findall(r'Lost =\s\d*',i))).group())
            if "Minimum" in i: average_latency = int(re.search(r'\d+', str(re.findall(r'Average =\s\d*',i))).group())

    Status.configure(text="Currently scanning every 10s...", background="Grey")

    StatusPacketLoss.configure(text="Packet(s) lost: {0}".format(packet_loss))
    StatusPacketLoss.configure(background=status_color(packet_loss))
    StatusLatency.configure(text="Average ms: {0}".format(average_latency))
    StatusLatency.configure(background=status_color(average_latency)) # Function for simplicity

    root.after(10000, scanning)

def status_color(x):
    # Determine Packet Loss Color
    color = "Green" if x == 0 else "Red"

    # Determine Average Latency Color
    if x <= 35: color = "Green"
    if 35 < x < 70: color= "Yellow"
    if x >= 70: color = "Red"

    return color
```

If anyone has any suggestions to remove redundancy or any excess, feel free to respond.

**new status_color function**:

```
def status_color(x):
    # Determine Packet Loss Color, best out of 4 pings
    if x == 0:
        color = "Green"
    elif x <= 4:
        color = "Red"
    # Determine Average Latency Color
    # Ping will never be low er than 4ms
    elif x <= 35:
        color = "Green"
    elif x <= 70:
        color= "Yellow"
    else:
        color = "Red"
```

Comment: Are you sure you want just one function for packet loss and latency? If so you may delete the first line as `color` will be overwritten

Comment: Ah i see what you mean by the first line being overwritten, as the code says `x <= 35` will turn green. So regardless of # of packet loss, it will always be green. I will change the 2nd condition in that function to `if 4 < x < 35: color = "Green"` and leave the first. My reason being that latency will never be below 4ms. And luckily the `ping` only checks for packet loss best out of 4 times. The script will no longer over-write, but could this solution be considered a poor way to go about things? Am I best just creating a separate function?

Comment: Yes, a separate function would make it much more obvious than this logic trick. Simple > Complex

Answer (score 1):

I got a question about the code, why use `\s` and not just enter a space and use `\d*,`?

What I mean is,

```
(r'Average = \d*',i)
```

Instead of

> ```
> (r'Average =\s\d*,i)
> ```

Why use `\s`? If we did not use it before the `=` sign?

Comment: You are right that it's an inconsistency, but I think maybe it should be `\s*` everywhere, to allow for both tabs and spaces and any number of them. Although `\s` allows line feeds as well, which should probably not be allowed. But for this case I think it is always using spaces so it's a good point that `= \d*` would be better.

Comment: If i understand correcrly, this is better and works too?
            if "Minimum" in i: average_latency = int(re.search(r'\d+', str(re.findall(r'Average = \d*',i))).group())